# Laravel When Condition on a column

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a ModelA with columns: name, last_name, email

I want ModelA with the name Test to add an extra where on email

what I tried is the following

```
$model_a_res = A::when(
function($query){
    return $query->where('name','Test');
},
function ($query) { 
    $query->where('email', 'NOT LIKE', '%@test%');})
->first();
```

I want this second where to only run on A with column name =  Test
however, this is not working.

I tried it with user name Mike and his email mike@test.com and he didn't appear in the result.

some data

```
id name email

1 Test test@test.com 
2 Test something@hotmail.com
3 Mike mike@test.com
4 Mike mike@hotmail.com
```

both 3 and 4 should be in the results
1 and 2 since they have name = Test will have another query which will check if he does have @test in his email if he does he will not be returned
returned Rows are 2, 3, 4

Comment: can't understand what you asking for

Comment: Tell us what the inputs are + what you expect as output.

Comment: Add extra querying, extra where condition if this row has the column name  = Test

Comment: This is an incomplete question.. Add more info to it

Comment: `when()` only executes the closure if the first argument is true. By that logic, your first parameter is not returning true. But we would need more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `when()` for this.

```
$model_a_res = A::where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', '!=', 'Test')
          ->orWhere(function ($query) {
              $query->where('name', '=', 'Test')
                    ->where('email', 'NOT LIKE', '%@test%');
          });
})->get();
```

Outputs

```
1 Test test@test.com  -  will skipp
2 Test something@hotmail.com - added
3 Mike mike@test.com  - added
4 Mike mike@hotmail.com  - added
```